# AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() picked up by main activity only the first time?

Tags: android, androidx

Running `Android P`, using `androidx 1.0.0` (`minSdkVersion 17`). From my `MainActivity` I open my `PreferenceActivity`. There I change the UI theme, and also re-create the activity to pick up the changes:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);
recreate();
```

After updating the theme, I return to `MainActivity`. There the theme is successfully updated. Then I re-open the `PreferenceActivity` and change the theme *again*.

**So far so good!**

Finally, I return to the `MainActivity` again. The theme is **NOT** updated, and it will not update if you repeat the steps!

**Thus, the steps to reproduce seem to be:**

1. From activity A, open activity B.
2. In B, call `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(`**MODE_NIGHT_YES**`)` and then `recreate()`. Theme is updated!
3. Return to A. Theme is updated!
4. Open activity B again.
5. In B, call `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(`**MODE_NIGHT_NO**`)` and then `recreate()`. Theme is updated!
6. Return to A. Theme is **NOT** updated and will **NOT** update if steps 3-6 are repeated!

I tried calling `recreate()` when returing from the `PreferenceActivity` but that yields another problem when the library *does* react on the theme change:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (...) {
        recreate();
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

That works when the library does NOT react on the updated theme. Otherwise the activity is recreated twice (possibly more when debugging), which kills performance etc:

```
D/MainActivity: onActivityResult(): instance 1
D/MainActivity: onResume(): instance 1
D/MainActivity: onPause(): instance 1
D/MainActivity: onDestroy(): instance 1

D/MainActivity: onCreate(): instance 2
D/MainActivity: onResume(): instance 2
D/MainActivity: onPause(): instance 2
D/MainActivity: onDestroy(): instance 2

D/MainActivity: onCreate(): instance 3
D/MainActivity: onResume(): instance 3
```

**Q:** What is going on with the `setDefaultNightMode()` API? And more importantly, how can I successfully update all running activities without the risk of re-creating them multiple times?

### UPDATE

There is a sample project demonstrating the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119757688

Comment: Any solution to this? I have been facing the same issue.

Comment: Sure. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Actually I found the issue somewhere elsewhere (WebView bug); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430282/1181261).

Comment: Interesting. It's obvious that toggling night mode is still error-prone.

Comment: The  sample project won't run for me, it says Themes are wrong. I think you left out files in res for the project.

Comment: Just tried it in AS 3.3. It compiles without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a *quite* simple solution to this problem. It works in both cases; when `AppCompatActivity` successfully recreates itself *and* when it fails to do so. Recall that activity `A` calls activity `B` where the theme is changed, then we return to `A` where the theme is not always updated.

### Activity B

In activity `B` - i.e. Preferences - we keep track of theme changes:

```
private boolean mThemeChanged;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mThemeChanged = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_THEME_CHANGED, false);
}

private void onNightModeChanged() {
    int nightMode = getNightModeFromPreferences();
    if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != nightMode) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);

        getIntent().putExtra(EXTRA_THEME_CHANGED, true);
        getDelegate().applyDayNight();
    }
}
```

And we provide this piece of information to the calling activity, i.e. Main:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_THEME_CHANGED, mThemeChanged);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

    super.finish();
}
```

### Activity A

Then in activity `A` we use this piece of information:

```
private boolean mShouldRecreateActivity;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ActivityResults.OPEN_SETTINGS_RESULT) {
        if (data != null && data.getBooleanExtra(SetPreferenceActivity.EXTRA_THEME_CHANGED, false)) {
            mShouldRecreateActivity = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mShouldRecreateActivity) {
        recreate();
        return; // No need to continue resuming!
    }
}

@Override
public void recreate() {
    super.recreate();

    mShouldRecreateActivity = false;
}
```

In the rare case (usually the first time) the `AppCompatActivity` correctly calls `recreate()` our flag will be reset, avoiding an additional recreation of the activity when we reach `onResume()`. Thus, this code **should be future-proof**. Though, I really hope the issue is fixed in the next version of `androidx`, allowing us to get rid of the workaround.

### UPDATE

Looks like this was fixed in `AppCompat 1.1.0`. I no longer need this workaround to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

When you change night Mode, store the mode value to shared preference.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);
recreate(); //only recreate setting activity 
...//store mode value, these lines are omitted,please complete yourself
```

In other activity onCreate() method:

```
...//get mode from share preference, these lines are omitted.
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode)//must place before super.onCreate();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: When returning from settings activity, `onCreate` is not called (unless I recreate the activity). The `setDefaultNightMode` method is called on Application startup. Everything works, except that the theme update mechanism seems to break after it has run once. I believe [this flag](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-cts-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java#47) in the Android source could be the culprit.