# Splash Screen Recreating After Calling AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

I am using the `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);` to set the Night Mode in my Android Application, whenever the user chooses any mode that preference configuration in the Shared Preferences on their device, now while I use the shared preferences to set the UI mode when the app starts from the Splash Screen Activity, the activity is getting recreated and then there are 2 instances of my app, as the Splash Screen intents to Landing Activity.

Here is my SplashScreen.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(UI_MODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        name = prefs.getString("uiMode", "System");
        applyUI();
        fireSplashScreen();
    }

    private void applyUI() {
        if (name.equals("Dark")){
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }
        else if (name.equals("Light")){
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
        else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        }
 private void fireSplashScreen() {
         Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Landing.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
    }
```

What can I do to avoid creating multiple instances of the Landing Activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to call `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` as soon as possible. E.g. before calling `super.onCreate()`. Ideally, you would want to call it in `Application.onCreate()`. Also, make sure to use the latest version of `AppCompat` (at least 1.1.0) or you might face this issue anyway.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600638/419761) for more details.